# How to create views grouped by title

Tags: 7, views

I want to build a view sorting it on the basis of the term field. I need to show the term as a title in each group, like this:

- Term 1:

  - node1
  - node2
- Term 2:

  - node3
  - node4
- Term 3:
  ...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps to show the view in this ways is**

- Create an Unformatted view showing Title and Terms.
  [image]
- Term field should be excluded from the display.
- Do a grouping of the term field.(Unformatted Format -> Settings)
  [image]

Save the view and check the result of the view.

Hope that this helps.